# Cayley graphs on $Z_{11}$ and $Z_p$

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, gap, cayley-graphs

I want to find all cayley graphs on $Z_{11}$. I know how many connected cayley graphs exist but i want to find all of them, connected or not, to find their eigenvalues. I found some of them and a theorem about isomorphism of caykey graphs on $Z_p$, p is a prime number. Also I trid to work with GAP to construct these cayley graphs but I can't.
I know cayley graphs on $Z_p$ are circulant. Is there any special property about the cayley graph on $Z_p$? Or is there any category for them?
Thanks for your helping.

Comment: The empty graph is the only disconnected Cayley graph on 11 vertices, so you should now be done.

Comment: This paper should be everything you need: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81945449.pdf

Comment: @Gordon Royle  Thanks for your answer but I know the number of these graphs. I want to find the graphs to obtain their eigenvalues.

Comment: @Adam P.Goucher thanks for your answer but I want to  construct these graphs on $Z_{11}$ to find their spectrums.

Comment: These are symmetric circulant matrices, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix and scroll down to “Symmetric circulant matrices”.

Comment: @Gordon Royle I studied that before but I coulden't use that. For $Z_11$, when |S| =4, S is a symmetric generate set for the cayley graph, we have 210 choices for this generate set.

Comment: @Gordon Royle I mean $Z_{11}$. Also I found this corollary ( at the top of 448) https://books.google.com/books?id=5l5ps2JkyT0C&pg=PA446&lpg=PA446&dq=cayley+graph%2BZ_p%2Ba+course+in+combinatorics&source=bl&ots=wVZR19KXtC&sig=ACfU3U2Ihs1Hm7ZbOuQjm1-qgkT_BR2tgA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjNuc3D5_PpAhWnyKYKHYBzApEQ6AEwAHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=cayley%20graph%2BZ_p%2Ba%20course%20in%20combinatorics&f=false and I used this for some generate sets. But my problem is there are 210 choices just for |S|=4, and I have to check all of generate sets with different cardinalities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are interested in graphs (not digraphs), then the elements of the connection set must come in pairs, so you are only looking at subsets 
$$
C \subseteq \{\pm1, \pm2, \pm3, \pm4, \pm5\}.
$$

Moreover, we know that the graph with connection set $C$ is isomorphic to the graph with connection set $kC$ ($k \ne 0$ and all calculations mod 11) so if the graph is not empty, we can assume that $\pm 1 \in C$.

So if $|C| = 1$, we get the $11$-cycle.

If $|C| = 2$, then either $C = \{\pm 1, \pm 2\}$ or $C = \{\pm 1, \pm 3\}$ (the choices $C = \{\pm 1, \pm4\}$ and $C = \{ \pm 1, \pm 5\}$ are each isomorphic to one of the previous ones.)

If $|C| > 2$ then the graph is the complement of one already found.

So you only have three graphs and their complements to check

Comment: Great! Thanks for your complete answer.